# Exists operator in sql query

Tags: sql, exists

Please, help me with this query in sql:

Using an EXISTS, list which items were sold in quantities (num_ordered) of 10 or more. The images needed are below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P89NK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRorV.png

Thank you very much!:)

Comment: Without query, How can others help you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from item item 
where exists 
     (select 1 from order_line order_line 
     where order_line.item_num = item.item_num 
     and order_line.num_ordered > 10)
```

Please try this.

Comment: Thank you very much:) can you explain to me, please, why you put 1 in the subquery? (select 1)

Comment: 1 has no significance there. It just returns 1 if where condition is satisfied. I could have as well put select "hello"  or select order_num instead of select 1. Query will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I understand:) Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you, please ,couple more queries if you have time, please? Thank you

Comment: Please ask your questions.